# Linear Regression with seasonality

Tags: regression, residuals, linear, seasonality

I triy to find a model to study the effect of temperature on my product data, which exibits a seasonalities(Day of the week, and Month)
I transformed the data using Ln and calculated the return as RT=Ln(Pt/Pt-1)

I then add Seasonal Dummies for the day of the week and month

I apply the linear regression and then got some strange residuals and do not know how to interpret them:

[image]
I
In The Residuals vs Fitted, There are some specific groups of residuals and I am unsure what they mean. We Also have almost an almost linear red line. IS everything ok on this side ?

The Normal Q-Q plot shows so long tail effect, yeat the main area is linear. Is it ok like this ?